# Can not upload new mac version to app store

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect, universal-purchase

I have an app out on the mac app store built with mac catalyst and I am trying to distribute the new update to App Store Connect. I get this error every time I try uploading a the version:

> "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleVersion [2] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously uploaded version [5]."

The last version I set up was "1.5" and the new version I am trying to send is "1.5.1". I even tried sending it with version "1.5.2" and "1.6" but get the same result. Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it? It works for the iOS version.

It worked on previous Mac versions but i just added a today widget to the project. The today widget is not for Mac so I don't think that matters, but that's the old new addition I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran into the same issue in the past. For me, my Mac app was built with Mac Catalyst and am using universal purchase. I had to increase the Build number to be higher than the build number of the last version. "Build" Number, not "Version" number. This is weird that we have to do this, but this probably a mac catalyst bug they will fix at some point. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly! I'm marking yours because your answer was sent first

Answer (score 0):

Look in the target editor, in the General pane. There are two values, the Version and the Build. The Version is something like 1.5. The Build is an integer shown in parentheses, such as 52. Together, they make something like `"1.5(52)"`. They *both* need to be incremented if this is a new release on the App Store.

Comment: yep! incrementing the build number helped!